# How to create Redo button in an Access form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm creating an Access form and would like to disable the ribbon and menus so that users can't re-enable the navigation pane, which would allow them access to delete/modify database records.

One problem with disabling the ribbon menu is that the user no longer sees the undo/redo buttons.

It seems that an undo button can be created from the UI: Design -> Button (click) and then choosing 'Undo Record' or pro grammatically using 'Me.Undo'

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to recreate a Redo button (no 'Me.Redo').

Is there a way to recreate a Redo button? or is enabling the ribbon menu the only way to have one? (Using Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your button click event

```
  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRedo
```

You'll probably want to add some error trapping.

Comment: I'm new to using Access. What kind of error trapping would you suggest?

Comment: This doesn't seem to behave the same as the Redo in the ribbon menu. When I type text and then undo the text is deleted. After that, if I press the redo button with this code, the deleted text doesn't reappear, whereas the redo button in the ribbon menu would make the text reappear

Comment: Interesting, I have to confess it's not something I have ever actually tried to do, just knew that most commands can be accessed via the RunCommand function.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is, that I disable the full ribbon and the navigation pane. You can do that under **File -> Options -> Current Database**, now uncheck **Display Navigation Pane** and **Allow Full Menues**. Or per code in the load event of your start form:

```
'Maybe an If condition to check for admin

 DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType", "acNavigationGroupTables"
 DoCmd.SelectObject acForm, vbNullString, True
 DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide

 DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Redo/Undo.

Comment: Well you have your redo button on the top left. The blue one from Access. So basically you dont need to implement one because he is already there. And you asked if enabling the ribbon menue is the only way. So here you have another way

Comment: I don't know what version of Access you're talking about but the Undo/Redo buttons also go away when I hide the ribbon menu in the version that I'm running.